# How to create this json projection on JMESPath?

Tags: json, jmespath, json-query

is this doable with JMESPath?

i want to transform this

```
{
  "common":  "value",  
  "subdicts": {
    "first": {"sub" : 10},
    "second": { "sub": 20}
  }
}
```

to

```
[
  {"common": "value",  "sub": 10}, 
  {"common": "value", "sub": 20}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it.

```
[
   {
      Common:common,
      Sub:subdicts.first.sub
   },
   {
      Common:common,
      Sub:subdicts.second.sub
   }
]
```

Result

```
[
  {
    "Common": "value",
    "Sub": 10
  },
  {
    "Common": "value",
    "Sub": 20
  }
]
```